# The type 'xxx' must implement the inherited abstract method java.awt.event.ActionListener.actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent)

Tags: java

I am trying to compile my code, but I keep getting a compiling error that I do not know how to fix. The error occurs at the line

```
public class MovingSignPanel extends JPanel implements ActionListener {
```

and the error is

```
The type MovingSignPanel must implement the inherited abstract method java.awt.event.ActionListener.actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent)
```

if one of you lovely people could help me it would be greatly appreciated.

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class MovingSignPanel extends JPanel implements ActionListener {

    JButton move = new JButton("Move");
    JButton quit = new JButton("Quit");//create buttons 
    private int press;
    private int x;
    private int y;
    private String time;

    public void CityPanel() {
        press = 0;
        this.add(move);
        move.addActionListener(this);
        this.add(quit);
        quit.addActionListener(this);
        x = 5;
        y = 175;//will be starting place for sun
        time = "8 AM";//will be starting time
    }

    public void moveSun(ActionEvent e) {
        if (e.getSource() == move) {
            {
                press = 0;
            }
            x = 5;
            y = 175;
            time = "8 AM";
            super.repaint();
        } else if (press == 1) {
            x = 100;
            y = 75;
            time = "10 AM";
            super.repaint();
        } else if (press == 2) {
            x = 250;
            y = 80;
            time = "12 PM";
            super.repaint();
        } else if (press == 3) {
            x = 350;
            y = 140;
            time = "2 pm";
            super.repaint();
        } else if (press == 4) {
            x = 415;
            y = 200;
            time = "4 PM";
            super.repaint();
        } else if (press == 5) {
            x = 465;
            y = 230;
            time = "6 PM";
            super.repaint();
        } else if (press == 6) {
            x = 500;
            y = 260;
            time = "8 PM";
            super.repaint();
        }
        press += 1;
    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        g.setColor(Color.black);//color for buildings
        g.drawRect(150, 275, 50, 80);
        g.drawRect(200, 250, 50, 100);//draw buildings
        g.drawRect(300, 300, 30, 60);
        g.drawRect(100, 275, 40, 40);
        g.drawLine(0, 350, 500, 350);
        g.drawString(time, x, y + 75);//gives time
        g.setColor(Color.yellow);//color for sun
        g.fillOval(x, y, 50, 50);//draws sun
    }
}
```

Comment: The error is self-explanatory: You have to implement `actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent)` method

Comment: `MovingSignPanel` implements the `ActionListener` interface. You need to declare and define the method `void actionPerformed(ActionEvent)` in the `class MovingSignPanel`

Comment: You need to know more about Java OOP.

Answer (score 2):

The `MovingSignPanel` class needs an `actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent)` method.
For example:

```
void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent ev)
{
    // your code
}
```

You need to do this because your class says it's implementing the `ActionListener` interface, and `actionPerformed()` is part of that interface.

Answer (score 2):

This is what your are missing

```
public class Test extends JPanel implements ActionListener {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
        // Do something here

    }
}
```

Also as a best practice never import packages with com.somepackage.* as you have in your code. If you are using eclipse use organize imports to clean that. It will make it more obvious what your are using and what not.
You should also try to replace the big if else in  "moveSun" method with a switch statement.