# Trouble interpreting Error

Tags: java, arrays, interface

I'm getting an error `"The type Octagon must implement the inherited abstract method Comparable<Octagon>.compareTo(Octagon)"` Not sure exactly what this means or how to fix it. I'd appreciate any help.

Here is the code :

```
public class Problem13_11 {
public static void main(String[] args) {
        Octagon Octagon1 = new Octagon(5);
        Octagon Octagon2 = (Octagon)Octagon1.clone();

        System.out.println("Compare Octagon1 and Octagon 2" + (Octagon1.compareTo(Octagon2)));
        System.out.println("Does Octagon1 equal Octagon 2?" + Octagon1.equals(Octagon2));
    }
}
class Octagon extends GeometricObject implements Comparable<Octagon>,Cloneable{
     private double side;

     public Octagon() {
         side = 0;
     }
     public Octagon(double side) {
         this.side = side;
     }
     public double getSide() {
         return side;
     }
     public void setSide() {
          this.side = side;
     }
     public double getArea() {
         return (2 + 4/ Math.sqrt(2) * side * side);
     }
     public double getPerimeter() {
         return side * 8;
     }
     public Object clone() {
         Object o;
         o = clone();
         return o;
     }
     @Override
     public boolean equals(Object o) {
        return o instanceof Octagon && getArea() == ((Octagon)o).getArea();
     }
     interface Cloneable{
            public void clone();
    }
     interface Comparable{
            public void compareTo();
    }
}
```

My goal is to write a class that implements Comparable and Cloneable interfaces. I believe I have accomplished all that, but I'm getting this error for some reason.

Comment: it tells you what to do, you have to implement a method called compareTo(Octagon) wich returns an int, check https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html for a simple example

Comment: You need to add a compareTo() method to your Octagon class.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [The type 'xxx' must implement the inherited abstract method java.awt.event.ActionListener.actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23379081/the-type-xxx-must-implement-the-inherited-abstract-method-java-awt-event-actio)

Comment: ^^ Different method, but same issue.

Comment: You've declared `implements Comparable<Octagon>` but then you didn't actually provide a `compareTo` method.

Comment: The error message is quite clear - what's the problem? I downvoted because there appears to have been no effort to solve this on your own.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to be able to compare two Octagon objects with one another and so in order to do that you implement the Comparable which in turn means you MUST implement the method public int compareTo(Octagon octangon). By saying you implement, you are accepting the contract that says you will implement every method that Comparable defines. In this case the method public int compareTo(Octagon octangon).

```
public int compareTo(Octagon otherOctagon)
{
    if(this.getArea() == octangon.getArea())
        return 0;
    else if(this.getArea() < octangon.getArea())
        return -1;
    else
        return 1; 
}
```

Since your Octagon's are equilateral shapes, you can simply compare the areas of your Octagon objects

Comment: Much better answer. Typically I see `if (this == otherOctagon) return 0;` to short-circuit what could be more expensive tests if they two are _the same object_. (imagine if .getArea() was computationally expensive)